# Hide Group Title in Form by hyperoslo

Tags: ios, forms

I do not want to show the *Group Title* but I cannot seem to find a way to do this. I have tried setting group title to empty string, nil, and not setting its value at all.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your style make all the headers transparent. Using UIAppearance:

```
[[FORMGroupHeaderView appearance] setHeaderBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

There's an example that does this. Check [Payment Demo](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Form/tree/master/Demos/Payment).

[image: simulator screen shot 28 oct 2015 19 12 11]

You can make only only of the headers transparent by sending any invalid HEX value, for example: `clearcolor`

```
[
  {
    "id":"group-id",
    "styles":{
      "background_color":"clearcolor"
    },
    "sections":[
      {
        "id":"section-0",
        "fields":[
          {
            "id":"email",
            "title":"Email",
            "type":"email",
            "input_type": "email",
            "size":{
              "width":100,
              "height":1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```